# Typescript flatten an array of Map

Tags: javascript, typescript, flatten

I have an array of `Map<string, number>`

How can I flat to a single map?

```
Map<string, number>[] to Map<string, number>
```

Thank you

Comment: With a loop? ...

Comment: Do you mind providing a sampled data here you're dealing with?

Comment: what happens with duplicate keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce` and create a new `Map` with the result:

```js
let map1 = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2]]);
let map2 = new Map([['c', 3], ['d', 4]]);
let maps = [map1, map2];

// reduce to a flattened array
let arr = maps.reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, ...val], []);

// create a new map using that array
let map3 = new Map(arr);
```